# How can I prevent iOS Simulator from presenting the "Do you want to try to reopen its windows again?" on launch, which breaks automation?

Tags: ios-simulator

Our test automation sometimes makes the simulator crash. In these cases, we often see the dialog below throw on the simulator's next launch. This modal UI dialog breaks automation by preventing application execution until the user chooses an action.

[image: Here is a picture of the UI presented]

Answer (score 0):

When the iOS Simulator crashes, the application state may be saved in `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.iphonesimulator.savedState`. The presence of this folder or values in the data within triggers the modal dialog.

Removing this folder (`rm -rf "~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.iphonesimulator.savedState")` before restarting iOS Simulator will prevent the dialog from appearing. This has been tested with iOS Simulator shipped in Xcode 9.4.1.